# How to make TypeScript Generics Type intelligence work as expected

Tags: typescript

I am working on a function which take a param and return it,the param is an object map,the problem is how to make the intelligence work with param and returned value,here have an image [Preview Gif Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glp3z.gif) explain what i want.

Thanks.

```js
// object 
interface P {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    desc?: string;
}


// params
interface Params<T> {
    [key: string]: P
}


// function 
function create<T>(params: T): T{
    return params
}



var s = create({
    item: {
        id: 1,   
        name:'name',         
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm unsure of your problem, but maybe you should read the documentation about [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

Comment: Dont get any useful info about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems perfectly fine in your animated GIF. If used without explicit typing, the **create** function takes **whatever** you stuff into it, as long as it complies with its function signature.

```
function create<T>(params: T): T;
```

Here **T** is arbitrary and the implicit type system matches **s** to the structure of the object literal you put into create. This is why you can access **.item** on **s**, but when you try **s["foo"].id** it won't work.

```
function create<T>(params: Params<T>): Params<T>;
```

This still works as expected. Argument **params** is now of an index signature, as well as the return type. The way you call create, the outer object literal suffices the index signature and the contained structure matches **P**. Now when you try **s.item** it won't work because there is no explicitly specified property **item** in your interface **Params**. But if you try **s["foo"].id** you'll see it works.

**Please note that this is just about type safety, which means: even if the compiler says it's fine, you can't access s["foo"].id at runtime when there is no "foo" there.**

It is important to understand the difference of **variable.some** and **variable["some"]** in TypeScript. The first requires **variable**'s type to feature **some**. The latter requires it either to feature **some** or to be of an **index signature**.

Your example is strange though, since your interface **Params** is of generic type, yet the generic **T** is not involved at all. So in case you're using the second of the above signatures, create itself is not generic but strictly typed against **Params** and therefore **P**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,maybe I should choose another way to solve my problem,I just want the autocomplete can works as expected.but don't have an solution right now.

Comment: But that is my point. It does work as expected. At what point does it not?

Comment: If a thing just has an index signature as your `Params` does, there is no way for the compiler (and intellisense) to know its property names. With an index signature `let p : Params<any> = {}; p[""+Math.random()] = foo;` is completely valid. But the property names of `p` are not known until runtime, and TypeScript won't actually **execute** your code.